# webpack compile all files in one folder into a file for each folder

Tags: webpack

The title might seem confusing, but I have a structure a bit like this:

-- src

----- project one

----- project two

When I run `npm run build` I want webpack to take all the files in **project one** and bundle them together, then do the same for **project two** and put them into the **dist** folder, but keeping the folder structure:

-- dist

----- project one

----- project two

I have setup my webpack like this:

```
const glob = require("glob");
const path = require("path");

const entryFiles = glob
.sync("./src/**/*.ts")
.reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
    return typeof previousValue === "string"
    ? {
        [path.basename(previousValue, path.extname(previousValue))]:
            previousValue,
        [path.basename(currentValue, path.extname(currentValue))]:
            currentValue,
        }
    : {
        ...previousValue,
        [path.basename(currentValue, path.extname(currentValue))]:
            currentValue,
        };
});

module.exports = {
    entry: entryFiles,
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts"],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /^(?!.*\.spec\.ts$).*\.ts$/,
            loader: "ts-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        ],
    },
};
```

but that doesn't work, they don't bundle or keep the folder structure :(
Help please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to achieve this lies in the entry object. Each key in your entry object should contain the desired target folder path. For example, in your case, you need the `entry` object to be like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'project1/main': './src/project1/main.ts',
    'project2/main': './src/project2/main.ts',
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  }
};
```

This should maintain the required directory structure in the `dist` folder:

```
dist
|--- project1
|    |--- main.bundle.js
|--- project2
|    |--- main.bundle.js
```

Since, you are generating your entry object dynamically using the glob pattern, you would need to maintain the structure in the **each key** of the `entry` object. So, you need:

```js
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

const entryFiles = glob
  .sync('./src/**/*.ts')
  .reduce((entryObj, currentValue) => {

    const parsedPath = path.parse(path.relative('./src', currentValue));

    // e.g. `project1/main`
    const entryValue = `${parsedPath.dir}${path.sep}${parsedPath.name}`;

    return {
      ...entryObj,
      [entryValue]: currentValue
    };
  }, {});


module.exports = {
  entry: entryFiles,

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },

  // Rest of the configuration...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it does create the folder which is brilliant, but it doesn't bundle all the files into one. If there are 3 files in the project folder, it create 3 files in the dist folder, I would like it to be one file in each project folder. Is that possible?

Comment: @r3plica Oh yes! It is possible. Right now it is taking all the files because that's the `glob` pattern you have provided `./src/**/*.ts`. Change it to only target the entry files. For example, if the entry files is named `main.ts`, then use something like `./src/**/*main.ts` or similar. This would ensure that only 1 file each project would be generated.